# How to stop and restart memcached server?

Tags: memcached

How to stop and restart memcached server 1.4.5 in linux OS from command line?

Comment: can anybody help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50135302/memcached-could-not-connect-to-remote-server-memcached-js

Answer (score 128):

Using root, try something like this:

```
/etc/init.d/memcached restart
```

Comment: it did not work- is there a need to creare script to stop and start as service?

Comment: well, it realy depends on your linux distribution and how you did install memcache. If you hav installed package of your distribution there should be memcached start/stop script (maybe it is in different directory like /etc/rc.d) If you installed memcached manualy you probably need also create star/stop script by yourself.

Comment: I had to add sudo

Answer (score 51):

Log in as root or do

```
su -
```

Then:

```
service memcached restart
```

If that doesn't work, then:

```
/etc/init.d/memcached restart
```

It all depends on which Linux distro (or other OS) you're using.

Comment: btw the dash after su is important, without it, it will report it can't find "service"

Comment: This was the correct answer for me, running Ubuntu and memcached as a service. Without specificing service, it does not work.

Comment: If you don't have root, but sudo privileges: `sudo service memcached restart`

Comment: on some systems `sudo su -` would work to change to root user.

Comment: if you have `sudo` (on Debian-based systems) no need for `su -`

Answer (score 29):

If you're using homebrew:

```
brew services restart memcached
```

Comment: Note that `services` is now considered an external tool to brew. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150300/need-help-using-homebrew-services-command

Comment: ...meaning you need to install it before you can use it: `brew tap homebrew/services`

Answer (score 26):

```
sudo service memcached stop

sudo service memcached start

sudo service memcached restart
```

Answer (score 9):

if linux

if install by apt-get

```
service memcached stop
service memcached restart
```

if install by source code

```
Usage: /etc/init.d/memcached {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}
```

can also simply kill $pid to stop

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart
```

Answer (score 7):

As root on CentOS 7:

```
systemctl start memcached
systemctl stop memcached
systemctl restart memcached
```

To tell the service to start at reboot (ex chkconfig):

```
systemctl enable memcached
```

To tell the service to not start at reboot:

```
systemctl disable memcached
```

Answer (score 7):

To shutdown memcache daemon:

```
sudo service memcached stop
```

To start memcached daemon:

```
sudo service memcached start
```

Restart memcached server:

```
sudo service memcached restart
```

You can see if Memcache is currently runing:

```
sudo ps -e | grep memcached
```

And you can check the TCP or UDP ports if something (e.g. Memcache) is listening to it:

```
netstat -ap | grep TheChosenPort#
netstat -ap | grep 11211
```

For some Linuxes you need to change your commands like:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/memcached start
sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart
sudo /etc/init.d/memcached stop
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be allowed to shutdown the memcached server you can give it that option before start it :

```
memcached -A &
```

With this option when you connect to memcached server for example:

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

then you can use `shutdown` command to shutdown the server. You can also  shutdown the memcached server when it is run as a process, first find the process PID using:

```
pidof memcached
```

then use:

```
kill PID command
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
brew services stop memcached
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an older version of memcached and need a script to wrap memcached as a service, here it is:
[Memcached Service Script](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-memcached-redhat-or-centos)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I installed it on a Mac via Homebrew and it is not set up as a service. To run the `memcached` server, I simply execute `memcached -d`. This will establish Memcached server on the default port, 11211.

```
> memcached -d
> telnet localhost 11211
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
version
VERSION 1.4.20
```

Comment: You can use the -d switch to launch memcached as a daemon (bit cleaner than backgrounding it)

Comment: How do you stop memcached if you started it with `memcached -d`?